# How can I measure elapsed time when encrypting using openssl in linux by C

Tags: linux, posix, libc

How can I calculate the amount of processing time used by a process in C on Linux.  Specifically, I want to determine how much time elapses when encrypting a file using openssl.

Comment: have look at `time()` or `clock()` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for you to do this is by using the `clock()` function from `<time.h>` to report the amount of CPU time used by the calling process.

From [SUSv4](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html):

> The clock() function shall return the implementation's best
>   approximation to the processor time used by the process since the
>   beginning of an implementation-defined era related only to the process
>   invocation.
>
> RETURN VALUE
>
> To determine the time in seconds, the value returned by clock() should
>   be divided by the value of the macro CLOCKS_PER_SEC.  If the processor
>   time used is not available or its value cannot be represented,
>   the function shall return the value (clock_t)-1.

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
 time_t start, end;
 double cpu_time_used;

 start = clock();
 /* Do encrypting ... */
 end = clock();
 cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```